# connect mysql with host ip redirected back to local

Tags: mysql, windows, vpn

I am trying to connect mysql to a VPN host, using the hamachi VPN. That host VPN IP is 25.41.6.111

so with the following command, it reported Access denied but with different host (POSSERVER). POSSERVER is my local hostname / client that I am using. Why is it using local hostname rather than that IP 25.41.6.111 ?

```
mysql -h 25.41.6.111 -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'POSSERVER' (using password:NO)
```

I can ping that host IP address, also the port 3306 has already been allowed in firewall rules.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it's just a simple issue, I didn't grant access  privilege to that user on the host server.